# “Bien de” vs “beaucoup de” : what is the difference?

Tags: grammaire, usage, superlatifs

I have seen both of these used to express "many of something" or "a lot of something" and I'm trying to understand when I should use which one, or what the differences are. For example:

> Il a eu beaucoup de chance.
>
> Je vous souhaite bien du courage.

Comment: Can you add an example of sentence where you've seen "Bien de" please? It sounds weird to me ... "Bien trop de", on another hand, can mean "way too much (of something)"

Comment: I could also think of "bien des fois, je me suis couché tot" but I cannot think of any example of "bien de"
Even "bien des" is used only in a limited amount of phrase. Such as "je te souhaite bien des choses" (I wish you all the best)

Comment: I can not agree more. I think that you should always use beaucoup de... It applies for both "many of something" and "a lot of something".

Comment: @Madlozoz Think of *bien du* or *bien de la*, not *bien de*: *bien* is always followed by a partitive article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executive summary:

- There is a grammatical difference: *bien* is followed by a [partitive article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive_article#Partitive_article) (singular or plural) whereas *beaucoup* is followed by the preposition *de*.
- There is a difference in register: *bien de* is rather formal, whereas *beaucoup de* is neutral.
- There is no clear semantic difference.

---

**Grammaticalement**, *bien de* et *beaucoup de* se construisent différemment. *Bien* est suivi d'un article partitif (singulier ou pluriel) et d'un nom, tandis que *beaucoup* est suivi de la préposition *de* et d'un nom.

> bien du plaisir / beaucoup de plaisir
>   bien de la peine / beaucoup de peine
>   bien des choses / beaucoup de choses

On peut aussi utiliser *bien* comme adverbe pour qualifier un adjectif ou un adverbe ; dans ce cas on ne peut pas utiliser *beaucoup*, mais *très*. Par contre, avec un comparatif ou un superlatif, c'est *beaucoup* qu'on utilise.

> bien grand / très grand
>   bien souvent / très souvent
>   bien plus loin / beaucoup plus loin
>   bien trop loin / beaucoup trop loin

Il y a quelques tournures dans lesquelles l'adverbe *bien* peut être utilisé mais les adverbes *beaucoup* et *très* doivent être remplacés par un adverbe ou une tournure plus spécifique.

> bien après / longtemps après
>   bien meilleur / largement meilleur
>   bien davantage / beaucoup plus
>   bien des fois / de nombreuses fois, souvent (*beaucoup de fois* est possible mais moins idiomatique)

La locution *bien de …* est d'un **registre** soutenu, tandis que *beaucoup de* est neutre. Utiliser *bien de* à l'oral peut paraître affecté en dehors de quelques expressions figées.

**Sémantiquement**, la différence entre *bien de* et *beaucoup de* est bien faible, si tant est qu'il y en ait une. Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bien) les qualifie de « (quasi)-synonymes ». Sur le [fil de discussion sur Word Reference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=685178&langid=6) cité par [jihed gasmi](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11355), certains contributeurs voient une nuance : [Montaigne](http://forum.wordreference.com/member.php?u=48095&s=d6d011026b1e2b72831a8cadfa5a9497) explique que

> "Il s'est donné bien du mal" peut impliquer l'idée de superflu, éventuellement d'insuccès, alors que "il s'est donné beaucoup de mal" mettrait plus l'accent sur l'opiniâtreté.

Pour ma part, je ne perçois pas du tout de telle nuance. Je ne vois dans ces deux phrases qu'une différence de niveau de langue.

Entre *bien* + adj./adv. et *très* + adj./adv., il y a une nuance plus marquée : *bien* est un peu plus vague que *très*, il peut être moins fort. Par exemple, « il est bien brave » est plus un intensifiant du fait qu'il est brave que du niveau de bravoure, autrement dit une insistance sur le fait qu'il est brave, tandis que « il est très brave » précise que le niveau de bravoure est élevé.

Comment: Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec la prétendue différence de niveau de langue. La différence sémantique expliquée par Montaigne est peut être difficile à généraliser, mais elle est présente dans tous les cas.

Comment: Indépendamment du niveau de langue, comme indiqué par @Gilles, la locution est plutôt *bien du* (bien+partitif) que *bien de*.

Answer (score 3):

Je vais contribuer avec le peu de chose que je connais et ma réponse ne fait en aucun cas autorité, comme quoi l'être humain ne peut aboutir qu'à des à-peu-près.

Pour commencer, examinons cette phrase :

> J'ai beaucoup de mal à comprendre les théories de la mécanique quantique.

On veut dire par cette phrase que le locuteur a beaucoup de difficulté à comprendre un sujet ou un thème.

> J'ai compris ce passage mais j'ai **bien des difficultés** à saisir la signification de la dernière phrase.

Ici, c'est plus complexe. En effet il y a juxtaposition de deux énonciations quasi-opposées : le locuteur comprend le thème en question **mais** admet néamoins certaines difficultés.

« Bien de » a une nuance plus subtile (comparée à « beaucoup de ») et vient pour **contrarier un pré-supposé**. Il faut lire entre les lignes :

> Cela n'apporte rien aux hommes et aux femmes qui ont donné leur vie et continuent de faire la fierté du Canada **à bien des égards**.

(exemple extrait de http://www.linguee.fr)

Tout se passe dans la tête de l'interlocuteur  qui essaie de réfuter et d'attaquer son interlocuteur, prêt a nier un énnoncé, en confirmant sa véracité.

J'envisage ce dialogue pour expliquer ça :

> — Mais qui utilise encore de nos jours les montres de poches?
>
> — AH ! et bien monsieur, figurez vous qu'il y'a **bien des gens** qui utilisent encore les montres de poche bien qu'ils auraient pu se contenter de consulter l'heure sur leurs smartphones.

(J'ai fait exprès pour la redondance du mot « bien ».)

> Bien des fois je t'ai averti d'éviter ce comportement.

Ici, c'est comme pour dire « attention, tu as été averti au moins une fois, tu ne peux pas nier cela » : « bien de » apporte de l'emphase, une **insistance** sur un fait.

En outre comme il a été signalé dans les commentaires sur cette page, l'usage de « bien de » est **restreint** et d'ailleurs son usage est d'un registre soutenu (littéraire).

> J’ai songé bien des fois.

(Titre d'un poème de François Porché.)

On peut lire dans un journal quotidien :

> Cela a suscité et continue encore à susciter bien des interrogations […]

Finalement, il faut utiliser « beaucoup de » quand il s'agit de focaliser sur le  grand nombre et laisser « bien de » à des cas spécifiques, surtout pour insister sur le fait que telle ou telle chose a eu lieu.

Il y a une discussion similaire (bien des gens / beaucoup de gens) sur [cette page](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=685178&langid=6).

Note:

En rédigeant ces lignes je me suis rendu compte que « bien+de+... » pourrait être interprétée de deux façon dans certains cas. L’ambiguïté est quelque chose d'intrinsèque aux langages naturels. Un exemple :

> J'ai bien du mal à terminer cet exercice.

Ici, « bien » pourrait être relié à « je » pour confirmer un fait.

> **J'ai bien** du mal.

(*avoir* ou *ne pas avoir de mal*)

On peut aussi relier « bien » à « du mal ».

> J'ai **bien du mal**.

pour focaliser sur l'intensité du mal.

(anecdotiquement *bien* et *mal* sont antagonistes...)

Comment: oh my god that first sentence is hard for me to read, im going to have to com back to this later

Comment: "comme quoi l'être humain ne peut aboutir qu'à des à-peu-près" --> WHAT?

Comment: @Aerovistae. It's a citation from *Jules Supervielle* : `L'homme ne peut aboutir qu'à des à-peu-près.` It means : "Man can only lead to some approximation".

Comment: Je ne vois pas de nuance de sens entre « bien des gens » et « beaucoup de gens », ou entre « bien du mal » et « beaucoup de mal ».